# What is the meaning "1" in the notation $\pi_{1}(X,x_0)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have just started studying algebraic topology and cannot understand the idea for this notation. We know that for a space $X$ and with a point $x_0\in X$ we define the fundamental group of $X$ as the set of path homotopy classes of the loops based at $x_0$ with the operation. We denote this be $$\pi_{1}(X,x_0)$$ But what do we mean by that $1$ in the notation of the fundamental group? After a bit of googling I got to know that $1$ means that the first homotopy group. So there must be something like the second homotopy group. But this does not make sense. How does one define the second group on the same base point?
Or even what I am thinking is right?

Comment: You already found the answer. Google "higher homotopy groups".

Comment: "But this does not make sense. " -- why?

Comment: I was not able think of a way to define two groups at the same base point .

Answer (score 3):

For every $n \geq 1$ we can define the $n$th homotopy group $\pi_1(X)$ of a pointed space $X$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group). The underlying set consists of homotopy classes of pointed maps $S^n \to X$. Notice that for $n=1$ this equals the fundamental group.

Comment: Thanks I get this. But why would one want to think of the nth fundamental group?

Comment: @Rememberme Because it's a further invariant of the space which picks up on information of a 'higher dimension'. All of the spheres $S^n$, for $n\geqslant 1$ are simply connected but can be distinguished by their $\pi_n$'s. Also, it naturally comes up even when thinking about just fundamental groups. Namely, one may wonder if one can describe $\pi_1$ of $\Omega X$ internally to $X$, and you can--it's just $\pi_2(X)$.

Comment: Please klick on the link.

Comment: @Remember The fundamental group cannot determine if $S^2$ is contractible, e.g. You need something like a "higher invariant" for doing that. $\pi_2$ does the job (so does $H_2$, but homology is often a weaker invariant than homotopy groups. Examples of this are complicated, at least for some who started studying algebraic topology)